# How to parse/filter this complex log file in log-stash config with multiple time stamps and lines

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have the following log file

```
2017-06-13 13:00:01,494 - INFO [Line: 48]: Begin logging

2017-06-13 13:00:01,494 - DEBUG [Line: 89]: Writing to lockfile. Lockfile location: /etc/conf/the/back_up.txt

2017-06-13 13:00:03,521 - WARNING [Line: 449]: Snapshotting is not enabled

2017-06-13 13:06:15,663 - INFO [Line: 898]: stderr: 

17/06/13 13:00:13 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=true, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=true,maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[/DAT/ABC], targetPath=/etc/conf/the/back_up.txt, tar getPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}

17/06/13 13:00:13 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://ip-192-168-X-XX.xyz:9000/v1/example/
17/06/13 13:00:14 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job log path: /var/tar/xar

17/06/13 13:00:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:22

17/06/13 13:00:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1495940390018_0989

17/06/13 13:00:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1495940390018_0989 
17/06/13 13:00:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495940390018_0989 running in uber mode : false
17/06/13 13:00:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 11% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 17% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 18% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 23% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 28% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 29% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 32% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 37% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 38% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 41% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 44% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 45% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 47% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:00:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 48% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 49% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 54% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 57% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 59% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 60% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 62% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 63% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 64% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 65% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 76% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 77% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 78% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 79% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 80% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 81% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 82% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:01:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 83% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 84% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 85% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 86% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 87% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 88% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 89% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 90% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 91% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 92% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 93% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 94% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 95% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:02:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 96% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:03:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 97% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:03:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 98% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:03:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 99% reduce 0%
17/06/13 13:03:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%

17/06/13 13:06:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495940390018_0989 completed successfully 

17/06/13 13:06:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 33
File System Counters
FILE: Number of bytes read=0
FILE: Number of bytes written=30634
FILE: Number of read operations=0
FILE: Number of large read operations=0
FILE: Number of write operations=0
HDFS: Number of bytes read=1810172
HDFS: Number of bytes written=6602
HDFS: Number of read operations=21710
HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
HDFS: Number of write operations=4461
Job Counters 
Launched map tasks=22
Other local map tasks=22
Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=09878
Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=170939
Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=17049
Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1747536
Map-Reduce Framework
Map input records=417
Map output records=175
Input split bytes=262
Spilled Records=0
Failed Shuffles=0
Merged Map outputs=0
GC time elapsed (ms)=3338
CPU time spent (ms)=3180
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=480768
Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=61798624
Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2965728
File Input Format Counters 
Bytes Read=17510
File Output Format Counters 
Bytes Written=6616
org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper$Counter
BYTESSKIPPED=11361
COPY=1242
SKIP=3175
2017-06-13 13:06:15,668 - INFO [Line: 904]: Distcp -log output stored in /var/AB/CY/

2017-06-13 13:06:15,673 - INFO [Line: 132]: End logging 

2017-06-13 13:07:01,494 - INFO [Line: 48]: Begin logging

. <similar to above logs>

. <similar to above logs>

. <similar to above logs>

2017-06-13 13:07:15,673 - INFO [Line: 132]: End logging
```

..
.

.
.
.

etc.

And then again it will have similar to the above part for different job IDs starting with "Begin Logging" and ends with "End Logging" as you see above in bold.

So my question here is: how can I parse that log in log-stash config, where I would like to see each block in one single ES log record. and what I mean by block is everything starting from "Begin Logging" till "End Logging" 
* note: I am still new to ES so any advice should be useful for me  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) for Logstash?
Here's some more documentation about storing multi-line events: [Managing Multiline Events](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiline.html)

I imagine in your case you can probably do something like this

multilineinput.config:

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "End logging"
      what => "next"
      negate => true
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "2017-06-13 13:00:01,494 - INFO [Line: 48]: Begin logging\n\n2017-06-13 13:00:01,494 - DEBUG [Line: 89]: Writing to lockfile. Lockfile location: /etc/conf/the/back_up.txt\n\n2017-06-13 13:00:03,521 - WARNING [Line: 449]: Snapshotting is not enabled\n\n2017-06-13 13:06:15,663 - INFO [Line: 898]: stderr: \n\n17/06/13 13:00:13 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=true, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=true,maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[/DAT/ABC], targetPath=/etc/conf/the/back_up.txt, tar getPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}\n\n17/06/13 13:00:13 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://ip-192-168-X-XX.xyz:9000/v1/example/\n17/06/13 13:00:14 INFO tools.DistCp: DistCp job log path: /var/tar/xar\n\n17/06/13 13:00:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:22\n\n17/06/13 13:00:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1495940390018_0989\n\n17/06/13 13:00:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1495940390018_0989 \n17/06/13 13:00:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495940390018_0989 running in uber mode : false\n17/06/13 13:00:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 11% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 17% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 18% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 23% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 28% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 29% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 32% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 37% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 38% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 41% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 44% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 45% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 47% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:00:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 48% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 49% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 54% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 57% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 59% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 60% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 62% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 63% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 64% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 65% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 76% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 77% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 78% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 79% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 80% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 81% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 82% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:01:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 83% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 84% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 85% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 86% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 87% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 88% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 89% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 90% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 91% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 92% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 93% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 94% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 95% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:02:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 96% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:03:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 97% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:03:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 98% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:03:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 99% reduce 0%\n17/06/13 13:03:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%\n\n17/06/13 13:06:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495940390018_0989 completed successfully \n\n17/06/13 13:06:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 33\nFile System Counters\nFILE: Number of bytes read=0\nFILE: Number of bytes written=30634\nFILE: Number of read operations=0\nFILE: Number of large read operations=0\nFILE: Number of write operations=0\nHDFS: Number of bytes read=1810172\nHDFS: Number of bytes written=6602\nHDFS: Number of read operations=21710\nHDFS: Number of large read operations=0\nHDFS: Number of write operations=4461\nJob Counters \nLaunched map tasks=22\nOther local map tasks=22\nTotal time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=09878\nTotal time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0\nTotal time spent by all map tasks (ms)=170939\nTotal vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=17049\nTotal megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1747536\nMap-Reduce Framework\nMap input records=417\nMap output records=175\nInput split bytes=262\nSpilled Records=0\nFailed Shuffles=0\nMerged Map outputs=0\nGC time elapsed (ms)=3338\nCPU time spent (ms)=3180\nPhysical memory (bytes) snapshot=480768\nVirtual memory (bytes) snapshot=61798624\nTotal committed heap usage (bytes)=2965728\nFile Input Format Counters \nBytes Read=17510\nFile Output Format Counters \nBytes Written=6616\norg.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper$Counter\nBYTESSKIPPED=11361\nCOPY=1242\nSKIP=3175\n2017-06-13 13:06:15,668 - INFO [Line: 904]: Distcp -log output stored in /var/AB/CY/\n\n2017-06-13 13:06:15,673 - INFO [Line: 132]: End logging ",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
{
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "\n2017-06-13 13:07:01,494 - INFO [Line: 48]: Begin logging\n\n. <similar to above logs>\n\n. <similar to above logs>\n\n. <similar to above logs>\n\n2017-06-13 13:07:15,673 - INFO [Line: 132]: End logging",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "multiline"
    ]
}
```